# Trying to parse JSON in Python. ValueError: Expecting property name

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to parse a JSON object into a Python `dict`. I've never done this before. When I googled this particular error, (*What is wrong with the first char?*), other posts have said that the string being loaded is not actually a JSON string.  I'm pretty sure this is, though.

In this case, `eval()` works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate way?

**Note:** This string comes directly from Twitter, via ptt tools.

```
>>> import json
>>> line = '{u\'follow_request_sent\': False, u\'profile_use_background_image\': True,
         u\'default_profile_image\': False, 
         u\'verified\': False, u\'profile_sidebar_fill_color\': u\'DDEEF6\',
         u\'profile_text_color\': u\'333333\', u\'listed_count\': 0}'
>>> json.loads(line)

Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
   ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Comment: That's just python syntax, not JSON. Use `ast.literal_eval` for safe evaluation

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's definitely not JSON - not as printed above anyhow.  It's already been parsed into a Python object - JSON would have `false`, not `False`, and wouldn't show strings as `u` for unicode (all JSON strings are unicode).  Are you sure you're not getting your json string turned into a Python object for free somewhere in the chain already, and thus loading it into json.loads() is obviously wrong because in fact it's not a string?

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Sometimes you can have this error because your string values are not well recognized by python. As an example: I've spent quite a lot of time searching for the origin of this kind of error. Here is what I found.

Sometimes a language recognizes a kind of quotes and not another one:
btw, to parse a string in to json in JavaScript all quotes have to be in the ' format

to parse a string into json in JavaScript all quotes have to be in the " format which is not really logic.

Hopefully you can use the replace function. For Python:

```
json.loads(s.replace("\'", '"'));
```

Hope it will save you the time I've spent hunting this bug!

Comment: The part of your answer regarding the quotes in JSON in JavaScript looks a bit contradictory. I went ahead and [tested](https://jsbin.com/pupayajoni/1/edit?js,console) both variants in JavaScript (in Chrome). The result is: your third paragraph is right: the standard JavaScript parser doesn't allow single quotes as string literal boundaries.

Comment: BTW [The JSON specification](http://www.json.org) only allows strings wrapped in double quotes so this behaviour isn't specific to JavaScript and Python JSON parsers.

Comment: thank you!!.. it worked!

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when I had a hanging comma at the end of a list of properties. Because of the comma it was expecting another property name but there was none.

Comment: Such a dumb thing that JSON doesn't allow trailing commas! And and an absolute no-go that json.load gives you only `ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JSON file does not have lines start with `//` (which wrongfully supposed to comments!). I have the same `ValueError` message and it's gone after I removed the `//` from my file.