# Decoding json data to Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, json-rpc

I am currently trying to create a dictionary from a json formatted server response:

```
{"id": null,{"version": "1.1","result": "9QtirjtH9b","error": null}}
```

Therefore I am using *json.loads()*. But I always get the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 12 (char 12)
```

I know that this means that there is an error in the json syntax and I found some threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187885/trying-to-parse-json-in-python-valueerror-expecting-property-name)) here at stackoverflow, but they did not include an answer that solved my problem.

However, I was not sure if the *null* value within the json response causes the error, so I had a closer look at the [json.org Reference Manual](http://www.json.org/) and it seems to be a valid syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the lack of a key for the nested object, not the `null`. You'd need to find a way to fix that syntax or parse it yourself.

If we make a few assumptions about the syntax, you *should* be able to use a regular expression to fix the JSON data before decoding:

```
import re
from itertools import count

def _gen_id(match, count=count()):
    return '{1}"generated_id_{0}":{2}'.format(next(count), *match.groups())

_no_key = re.compile(r'(,)({)')

def fix_json(json_data):
    return _no_key.sub(_gen_id, json_data)
```

This assumes that any `,{` combo indicates the location of a missing key, and generates one to insert there. That is a reasonable assumption to make, but may break things if you have string data with exactly that sequence.

Demo:

```
>>> json_data = '{"id": null,{"version": "1.1","result": "9QtirjtH9b","error": null}}'
>>> fix_json(json_data)
'{"id": null,"generated_id_0":{"version": "1.1","result": "9QtirjtH9b","error": null}}'
>>> json.loads(fix_json(json_data))
{u'id': None, u'generated_id_1': {u'version': u'1.1', u'result': u'9QtirjtH9b', u'error': None}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid. The outer object needs a property name for the second element; raw values are not valid in an object.

```
{"id": null, "somename":{"version": "1.1","result": "9QtirjtH9b","error": null}}
```

Comment: Ok, I missed that. But how could I add an own object name to such results without knowing the exact structure of the result? I could not force the server to create a valid response, so I have to fix it myself, but I do not know the exact formatting rules of the server.

Comment: You're going to have to brute-force parse the string.

Comment: Since the error raises while json parser parses the string, you can not handle it directly. Best approach would be writing your own parser, or you may write a function that will take the string and examine it, and make accurate changes before parsing it with `json`.